# Является ли в данном предложении "кроме того" вводным, нужна ли запятая после него?

Tags: пунктуация

*Кроме того можно проверить учеников нашего учителя.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно же это вводное сочетание, и запятая нужна. Ведь у нас значение *вдобавок.* Если бы это был член предложения, тогда под "тем" подразумевался бы ученик *(Кроме того ученика можно проверить и учеников учителя),* но тут явно не такой смысл, потому что, если бы был такой, нельзя было бы так запросто опустить этого "ученика" в этом случае.